# Generating an HTML code from a flask server

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a pythonic Flask server with a list that has some elements. This list has some entries. I want to produce a html page with the elements of the list.

Note: I am building a app where this list has all the things that the user shopped and then at the end we need to show the list of shopped things. I stored in the list using request.form().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use [`flask.render_template`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/?highlight=render_template#flask.render_template) to do this.

That function takes one positional argument and as many keyword arguments as you want. Use it like this.

```
from Flask import render_template

@yourApp.route('/your/path')
def renderThisPath:
  res = render_template('your-jinja2-template-file.html', 
                       some='variables',
                       you='want',
                       toPass=['to','your','template'])
  return res
```

then your template you'd do this:

```
<html>
<!--head etc-->
<body>
  <div>{{ you }}</div>
  <div>{{ some }}<span>?</span></div>
  <!-- you can iterate on a list to add many items -->
  {% for v in toPass %}
    <div>{{ v }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

renders:

```
<html>
<!--head etc-->
<body>
  <div>want</div>
  <div>variables<span>?</span></div>
    <!-- you can iterate on a list to add many items -->
    <div>to</div>
    <div>your</div>
    <div>template</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my argument in the return render_template is a list. When I pass a list, an error pops out.

Comment: What does the error say? And how did you make your `render_template` call?

Comment: In your list named toPass, you know the elements and specify them inline. However, I dont know the number of elements neither the element but I want to pass the same list to the html and use {{this binding}} to display the list. Thanks for the former reply.

Comment: I used strings, but you can pass in whatever you like. It sounds like you want to use a list comprehension, you could do: `render_template('file.html', myData=[item for item in myList])` where `myList` is the list whose size you don't know

Comment: At some point you have to just make a decision about what tag names to use. Or are you saying that your list contains html markup already?

Comment: myData=[item for irem in mylist] . How does this actually work?

Comment: think of it like this: `myData = []`  `for item in myList:`   `myData.append(item)`